# How to create a custom tooltip in highstocks

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock chart with range selector and as well as data grouping it is working fine, but facing issue with custom tooltips in highstock chart(I am able to generate custom tooltip in highchart, but this is not wotking in highstock). Please, anyone, help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom tooltip in Highstock in the same way as in Highcharts:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return 'Custom tooltip: x: ' + this.x + ' y: ' + this.y;
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q7undao5/1/

**API Refernce:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Hi ppotaczek, 
Thank you for response.
It is working but in our case having multiple series in one month like Jan (3 bars and  3 lines). I am expecting individual tooltip for each series. please help with this.

Comment: Hi @Satyanarayana, You need to disable `split` property for tooltip. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q7undao5/2/